# Singleton classes and memory usage

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns

General question on using Singleton classes in an AS3 application: If I have a data model that is pretty complex, and have lots of different view classes that have a reference to the model instance, does performance get sacrificed?

In other words, I want all my view components to extend a base class that has a reference to the model. Will that affect the performance of my app? Or is it okay because they're just pointers referencing a singleton instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to let all your views have access to the model, just because you *may* need it.

Other than that, I see no problem. The views will simply hold a reference to some object, which comes at a cost of 4 Byte per reference, which is basically negligible in comparison to all the memory views actually need.
Technically, accessing fields is faster than accessing global objects (class objects are global objects for example), but in this case I also doubt this will matter.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton is extremely bad practice (http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/21/clean-code-talks-global-state-and-singletons/). Class instances, especially Views, should only have references that you *give* them. They shouldn't be able to reach out and get their data out of the ether.

But, aside from that, if you add any event listeners to your Singleton, you could cause memory leaks (your Views will not be able to be garbage collected) http://www.developria.com/2010/08/rethinking-addeventlistener-an.html.

Comment: Singletons are not bad practice. Singletons are actually a good idea per se. The point is that making the assumption that some object is a singleton is a bad practice. I've attempted an explaination [in my blog](http://back2dos.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/stop-singleton-abuse/).

Comment: By having a static getInstance() method, you make the instance available globally, and that pretty much guarantees that it will be used for global state.  However, the biggest problem is that now you are locked into that one implementation, and you can't sawp out something else (for instance, for writing the unit tests that you do have, right? No, of course you don't because you CAN'T if you are using Singleton).

Comment: `SomeClass.getInstance()` is equivalent to `new SomeClass`, only that in the former case the called code has control, because it can decide to limit instantiation to a single object, or it can decide to actually return a subclass. You speak of *the instance*. There is no such thing. If the client code assumes that `getInstance` returns the same object again and again, then the client code is the problem. Otherwise there is no problem.

Comment: No, it's only equivalent to that the _first_ time you call it.  Most times people are using Singleton, they are using it primarily to guarantee global access, as the original poster is. If you're not always returning the same instance, then you're not using Singleton. If you only want one instance, the way to do it is to simply only make one instance, and then pass that to whatever needs it. Those things that need it should never need to know how it is created, only that it is supplied when needed.

Comment: The person *implementing* a Singleton is the one *using* a Singleton. You cannot use a Singleton from outside, because Singleton is a matter of implementation, not of consumption. The Singleton is a *creational pattern* and any other pattern beyond that, that might resemble to the Singleton is not the Singleton. The case you speak of is the edge case of a global Registry at best.

Comment: It sounds to me like you haven't worked on many multi-developer projects, and you are also not using TDD.  So you're going to have a hard time seeing the issues as I do.